# thymeleaf: processing attributes of elements

Tags: spring, attributes, spring-boot, thymeleaf, processor

In my current spring-boot project, I have implemented an **AbstractTextChildModifierAttrProcessor** class to handle tags like this:

```
<p get:property="xxx,yyy"></p>
```

which it's processed to that:

```
<p>zzz</p>
```

but now I am looking for something similar, but for use with tags `th:if` and `<a>` like this:

```
th:if="..."
```

and

```
<a th:href="..."></a>
```

the custom processor should be placed as the attribute of the tag, and return a text value for this attribute.

Someone can give a hint about how to do that, with this same processor **AbstractTextChildModifierAttrProcessor** or another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `href` attribute I get a solution by using the class:

```
AbstractAttributeModifierAttrProcessor
```

in the view I use:

```
get:href="Suporte,faq"
```

and the `th:if` tag I was be able to get a similar result with the class:

```
AbstractConditionalVisibilityAttrProcessor
```

in the view I use:

```
get:if="Suporte,faq"
```

Links:

- http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.0.17/org/thymeleaf/processor/attr/AbstractAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.html
- http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.0.21/org/thymeleaf/processor/attr/AbstractConditionalVisibilityAttrProcessor.html